# Add java class to jython as jython import module

Tags: java, python, import, jython, pythoninterpreter

I am using jython interpreter programmatically (PythonInterpreter) in my java application, and I'd like to add a specific class, eg. MyJythonLib as a Jython import module so that my Jython script could have something like:

```
import MyJythonLib
a = MyJythonLib.getStuff()
```

where MyJythonLib.java is

```
public class MyJythonLib
{
    private Object stuff;
    public Object getStuff()
    {
        return stuff;
    }
}
```

How do I set this class to be a module for my Jython interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure `MyJythonLib` is in your classpath.
2. `import` `MyJythonLib` with reference to its fully qualified name.

For example:

```
import com.mycompany.MyJythonLib
```

Or:

```
from com.mycompany import MyJythonLib
```

Or:

```
import com.mycompany.MyJythonLib as MyJythonLib
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured Jython searches classpath, but I am not sure how to add the package to classpath.
I thought I could somehow search for compiled files during debug session and built application with:

`URL package= MyJythonLib.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/");`
`URL bundleLocation = FileLocator.resolve(package);`
`File file = new File(bundleLocation .toURI());`
And then set this path as a search path for modules...
Is there any way to do it like this?